# Apps Script not updating sheet, no error in script

Tags: google-apps-script

This apps script is supposed to update two columns in my Inv sheet with dates. One column is next appt date and the other column is Due date. It gets the dates from my sheet called fromWip. This script was attached to a time based trigger that ran once a week. The script runs without error and worked without issue until this week. I haven't changed order of columns in any of the sheets or the script. It is also tied to an AppSheet app.

```
function apptDates() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var wipShirtAltSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("WipShirtAlt");
  var wipEAaltSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("WipEAalt");
  var fromWipSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("fromWip");
  
  var invSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Inv.");
  
  // Get the data range of the "WipShirtAlt" sheet
  var wipShirtAltDataRange = wipShirtAltSheet.getDataRange();
  var wipShirtAltData = wipShirtAltDataRange.getValues();
  
  // // Get the data range of the "WipEAalt" sheet
  var wipEAaltDataRange = wipEAaltSheet.getDataRange();
  var wipEAaltData = wipEAaltDataRange.getValues();
  
  // Get the data range of the "fromWip" sheet
  var fromWipDataRange = fromWipSheet.getDataRange();
  var fromWipData = fromWipDataRange.getValues();
  
  
  // Get the data range of the "Inv." sheet
  var invDataRange = invSheet.getDataRange();
  var invData = invDataRange.getValues();
  
  // // Iterate over the rows of "WipShirtAlt" sheet
  for (var i = 1; i < wipShirtAltData.length; i++) {
    var clientName = wipShirtAltData[i][1]; // names/client is the 2nd column (index 1)
    var date = wipShirtAltData[i][5]; //  column where appt dates stored is the sixth column (index 5)
    var due = wipShirtAltData[i][4]; // column where the due date is stored if the 5th column (index 4)
    
  //   // Search for a matching name in "Inv." sheet
    for (var j = 1; j < invData.length; j++) {
      if (invData[j][0] === clientName) { // names/client is the 2nd column (index 1)
        invSheet.getRange(j + 1, 2).setValue(date); //  column B is the second column (index 2) where appt column is
        invSheet.getRange(j + 1, 3).setValue(due); //column C is the third column (index 3) where wip due date column is
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  
  // // Iterate over the rows of "WipEAalt" sheet
  for (var k = 1; k < wipEAaltData.length; k++) {
    var clientName = wipEAaltData[k][1]; //  names/client is the 2nd column (index 1)
    var date = wipEAaltData[k][4]; //  column e is the fifth column (index 4)
    var due = wipEAaltData[k][5]; //column f is sixth column (index 5)
    
  //   // Search for a matching name in "Inv." sheet
    for (var l = 1; l < invData.length; l++) {
      if (invData[l][0] === clientName) { //  names/client is the first column (index 1)
        invSheet.getRange(l + 1, 2).setValue(date); // column B is the second column (index 2)
        invSheet.getRange(l + 1, 3).setValue(due);  //column C is the third column (index 3) where wip due date column is
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  
  // Iterate over the rows of "fromWip" sheet
  for (var m = 1; m < fromWipData.length; m++) {
    var clientName = fromWipData[m][1]; //  names/client is the 2nd column (index 1)
    var date = fromWipData[m][5]; //  column f is the 6 column (index 5) next appt
    var due = fromWipData[m][4]; //column e is the 5th column (index 4) due date
    
    // Search for a matching name in "Inv." sheet
    for (var n = 1; n < invData.length; n++) {
      if (invData[n][0] === clientName) { //  names/client is the first column (index 0)
        invSheet.getRange(n + 1, 2).setValue(date); //  column B is the second column (index 2)
        invSheet.getRange(n + 1, 3).setValue(due);  //column C is the third column (index 3) where wip due date column is
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I removed the time based trigger and ran the script from Appscript extension page. The script runs successfully and no errors show in execution log but the dates are not input into the Inv. sheet like they had done previously. When the script is run, nothing is added or changed in the Next Appt. Column (column b) of the Due Date Column (column c) of my Inv. Sheet.

Comment: Are you able to share an example spreadsheet that roughly mimics what you are seeing? It's a little hard to understand the structure of the source spreadsheet just based on the comments. I will say I usually prefer to work with `getDisplayValues` as opposed to `getValues` as `getDisplayValues` always returns strings, whereas `getValues` returns the data as it's formatted in the spreadsheet (ie number, date, boolean, etc), which can unintentionally be changed from how individual cells are formatted (and dates are notoriously difficult to work with).

Comment: not updating the spreadsheet is not an error as far as the code is concerned

Comment: Please limit the scope of you [mcve] to the scope of your question.  I don't wish to debug all of you code...that's your problem not mine.